# SQL- accessing a column from a nested query

Tags: sql, sqlite

My table is something like this:

```
_id     time    name    isNotFirstEntry
1       55555   aaa     0
2       66666           1
3       77777           1
4       88888   bbb     0
5       99998           4
6       99999           4
```

i.e. for duplicate entries, `name` is null and the `_id` of the original entry is stored in isNotFirstEntry.

I want do retrieve _id, time, name, no. of duplicate entries as n where name!=null

I tried something like this:
`select _id, time, name, (select count(isNotFirstEntry) from mytable where isNotFirstEntry=_id) as n from mytable where name!=null`

but of course that doesnt work. The _id in the nested query is not the same as that of the outside part. I need to access _id of the outside part from the nested query.

Im using android sdk, so i can use sqlite only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a join.  You can do this as a correlated subquery:

```
select mt._id, mt.time, mt.name,
       (select count(mt2.isNotFirstEntry)
        from mytable mt2
        where mt2.isNotFirstEntry=mt._id
       ) as n
from mytable mt
where mt.name!=null
```

Or as an explicit join with group by:

```
select mt._id, mt.time, mt.name, count(mt2._id) as n
from mytable mt left outer join
     mytable mt2
     on mt._id = mt2.isNotFirstEntry
where mt.name is not null
group by mt._id, mt.time, mt.name
```

Comment: saved my day! btw specifying the inner table as mt2 isnt necessary in the first method

Comment: No, you could leave the alias.  However, I think it is good practice to use aliases and to specify them when using columns.

Comment: I would've wanted to use an alias on an outer column instead of an alias on the whole outer table, but apparently that's not possible. Any idea why? Ex: 

`select _id as checkedId, time, name, 
(select count(isNotFirstEntry) 
from mytable 
where isNotFirstEntry = checkedId ) as n 
from mytable 
where name!=null`